# LetterSpace (tracking) of monospace fonts in Xetex/fontspec

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec, typewriter, letterspacing

How can I increase the letterspacing (tracking) of monospace fonts in Xetex?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=0}
HLHHLLH\\
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50.0}
HLHHLLH\\

\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=0}
\texttt{HLHHLLH}\\
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50.0}
\texttt{HLHHLLH}\\

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: screenshot of rendering of non-tracking in fontspec monospace font]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the \addfontfeature inside the \texttt, and you must load the fonts with the fontspec commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\begin{document}

\texttt{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50}HLHHLLH}

\end{document}
```

[image]